# chipmunks: how to make to objects stick together after they hit each other

Tags: join, cocos2d-iphone, collision, chipmunk

Hi I am using chipmunks on my cocos2d project.  I have two objects and when they collide, I like them to join and move together like one object?  How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a collision callback and add a joint between them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  That is what I did.  But does not work very well.  What kind of the join do you recommend?  I tried pinjoin, slidejoin.